# SQL Server : RegEx ASCII removal

Tags: sql-server, regex, collation, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

Looking for a way to make a case-sensitive search.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_StripCharacters]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @RemoveFollowing VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @RemoveFollowing =  '%['+@RemoveFollowing+']%'
    WHILE PatIndex(@RemoveFollowing, @String) > 0
        SET @String = Stuff(@String, PatIndex(@RemoveFollowing, @String), 1, '')
    RETURN @String
END
GO

SELECT dbo.fn_StripCharacters('RoaR! rings the roll', '\R')
```

- Supplied input:    'RoaR! rings the roll'
- Expected output:   'oa! rings the roll'
- Output received:   'oa! ings the oll'

RegEx tried before (no success): '\R', '\x52', '\n42', '\u0052', 'R'.

I have also tried to Collate the database, and no result:

```
COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CS_AS_SC;
```

---

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      12.0.4100.1

Microsoft .NET Framework                    4.0.30319.34011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using a loop? All you are trying to do is replace a certain letter with an empty string? You need to specify the collation for your input to make it case sensitive.

```
select replace('RoaR! rings the roll' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, 'R', '')
```

Comment: Your code has an output of: 'oa! ings the oll'.

I am using a loop, because it is used for a whole table, but the idea is the same.

Comment: No, I had to add the collation to make this case sensitive.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean that you need a loop because you are doing this to a table.

Comment: I have removed the loop, the who function actually :) but your code still doesn't work. It removes characters, while being case insensitive.

Comment: What version of sql server are you using? It does NOT remove lower case r because of the collation. I am a bit confused though because you say it doesn't work but you also marked it as the answer. >.<

Comment: 12.0.4100.1, and it doesn't work. Sorry for confusion, I thought it did, for a second. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Ok wait, i found my mistake... Damn